# EasyMock failed with java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, easymock

I have below -

```
List<Long> getEmployeeId(Long deptId, Date joiningDate, List<String> technologies);
```

I am trying to write a `Junit` for above method by using `EasyMock`

```
EasyMock.expect(empDao.getEmployeeId(EasyMock.anyLong(),  EasyMock.anyObject(Date.class),EasyMock.anyObject(List.class))).andReturn(empIdList).anyTimes();
replay(empDao);
```

but I am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException` for `EasyMock.expect(..)`

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I will need a bit more input. The EasyMock version, the full error and so on. Because when trying the following, it works perfectly.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.anyLong;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.anyObject;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.mock;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.replay;

public class MyTest {

    public List<Long> getEmployeeId(Long deptId, Date joiningDate, List<String> technologies) {
        return null;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyTest test = mock(MyTest.class);
        expect(test.getEmployeeId(anyLong(), anyObject(Date.class), anyObject(List.class))).andReturn(Collections.emptyList()).anyTimes();
        replay(test);
    }
}
```